# ElasticSearch MYSQL Count Votes Performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic Search on a `thread` index matching with `title` and `body`.

I have a votes table to count number of votes per thread.

I'm doing an **Autocomplete** search using ElasticSearch . But I also want to sort the search results  using the vote count ( it is normalized ) .

In order to sort by votes I HAVE to use MYSQL and thus hit the database using the primary ID `thread_id` i received from elasticsearch.

Assuming the vote count per thread can reach (1k-50k) ,

Is hitting the database after elastic search good for autocomplete (performance wise) ?

Or is there any workaround ?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.  It will clarify many question about your vague schema descriptions.

Comment: Also, provide the `SELECT` that is performing poorly.